# We have been friends/we were friends for a long time

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-perfect, present-tense

When I want to say that we were friends in the past, and we are still friends I will use present perfect tense, right?

i.e, **We've been friends for 20 years.**   (Implied:  We are still friends.)

But when I want to say that somebody had been my friend for 20 years until we had an argument, will I say:

"We were friends for 20 years" or 
"We had been friends for 20 years"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"We were friends for 20 years" adequately conveys the past tense, making it clear that we are no longer friends. This is sufficient for a simple sentence.The past perfect form "we had been" needs to be used only when the next part of the sentence describes a more recent (past tense) event, as in

> We **had been** friends for 20 years, but an irreconcilable dispute **ended** the friendship.
>
> We **had been** friends for 20 years, but **clashed** irrevocably over an ideological issue.

Note: when the second part of the above sentence is constructed in the present perfect tense, "we were" should replace "we had been" in the first part.

> We **were** friends for 20 years, but **have clashed** irrevocably this month over an ideological issue.